# What's the determinant of this $n$ by $n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, pattern-recognition

I would like to know if there's some way of computing the determinant of the $n$-th order square matrix whose diagonal entries are $1$ while the rest equal some constant $a$, so

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a & \cdots & a \\
a & 1 & a & \cdots & a \\
a & a & 1 & \cdots & a \\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a & a & a & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I tried computing some cases, so

- $n=1$ gives $1$,
- $n=2$ gives $1-a^2$,
- $n=3$ gives $1-3a^2+2a^3$,
- $n=4$ gives $1-6a^2+8a^3-3a^4$

and I noticed some patterns. First off, the 0th order on $a$ is always $1$ and the first is always $0$. The second is minus the $n-1$th triangular number and the $n$th is $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$.

With these, I thought I could maybe do some induction and compute the $n$th order determinant from the $n-1$th using minors or something, I think that's probably the best way to do it, but I get confused all the time and the expressions I get are very ugly. Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: Hint: use Lapace's formula in your induction process.

Comment: If we have $a=0$ , the determinant is obviously always $1$. If we have $a=1$ , the detrminant is obviously $0$, hence all the polynomials must be divisible by $a-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we let $A_{ij}=a+(1-a)\delta_{ij}$ we see that
$$A-(1-a)I$$
has rank $1$ so $1-a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $n-1$. Since the sum of all eigenvalues is $\operatorname{Tr}A=n$, the last eigenvalue is $n-(n-1)(1-a)=1+(n-1)a$ so the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues:
$$\det A=(1-a)^{n-1}\left(1+(n-1)a\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general way how to solve these problems. Write
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a & \cdots & a \\
a & 1 & a & \cdots & a \\
a & a & 1 & \cdots & a \\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a & a & a & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = (1-a) E + a \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\1\\
\vdots\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot(1, 1, \cdots, 1)
$$
with $E$ the unit matrix. By the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we have
$$
\det (A) = (1 + a\frac{1}{1-a}(1, 1, \cdots, 1) \cdot E \cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\1\\
\vdots\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}  )(1-a)\det E 
\\
= (1-a)^n + a n (1-a)^{n-1} = (1-a)^{n-1} (1-a + a n)$$
and your results confirm with that.